# Javascript ignoring variable in switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to make a case statement but my variable for my first switch statement just goes to my default statement when i really have a string in my variable for the type of edge such as: "round", "square", "butt". I tested it with alert(tipoextremo) and it does contain the value "round", "square", or "butt".

For the second switch statement, i am trying to get my button names into the switch statement when i click a button in html and do that function inside the case, but when using alert("hi") it does not even go into the default statement meaning that it is being completely ignored in my javascript.

Botones
                
                    Borrar
                
                
                    Varias Lineas
                
                
                    Arco
                
                
                    Cuadratica
                
                
                    Berzier
                
                
                    Zig Zag
                
                
                    Espiral

```
    <section id="parametros">
        <form action="" method="post" name="parametro">
            Color: <input type="text" name="btncolor" id="color" value="red"><br/>
            Ancho: <input type="text" name="btnancho" id="ancho" value="10"><br/>
            Tipo Extremo: <br/>
            Round   <input type="radio" name="btntipoextremo" value="round" id="tipoextremo" checked="checked"><br/>
            Square  <input type="radio" name="btntipoextremo" value="square" id="tipoextremo"><br/>
            Butt    <input type="radio" name="btntipoextremo" value="butt" id="tipoextremo"><br/>
            <button name="btnOK" type="button" value="OK" onclick="parametros()">OK</button>
        </form>
   </section>
```

This is my javascript part.

```
function parametros() { 
//var nombre = document.parametro.btncolor.value;
//alert(nombre);

contexto.beginPath();
color = document.getElementById("color").value;
ancho = document.getElementById("ancho").value;

alert(color);
alert(ancho);

var boton_te = document.forms[0];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < boton_te.length; i++) {
    if (boton_te[i].checked) {
        tipoextremo = tipoextremo + boton_te[i].value + " ";
    }
}

document.getElementById("tipoextremo").value = tipoextremo;
alert(tipoextremo);

$("button[type='button']").click(function()
{
    switch(this.name){
    case 'btnarco':
        fun_arco(color, ancho, tipoextremo);
        alert("Hi");
        break;
    case 'btncuad':
        fun_cuad(color, ancho, tipoextremo);
        break;
    case 'btnbezier':
        fun_bezier(color, ancho, tipoextremo);
        break;
    case 'btnzigzag':
        fun_zigzag(color, ancho, tipoextremo);
        break;
    case 'btnespiral':
        fun_espiral(color, ancho, tipoextremo);
        break;
    default:
        alert("hi");
    break;
    }
});
}
```

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`. This is telling you that $ is an undefined variable. Did you not load jQuery into your project?

Comment: yeah i have my jquery defined in my html, that is not the problem anymore ill edit, but my tipoextremo variable when i click on a button again its getting "square round" then i click again "square round round" and its entering the first switch but the second switch keeps getting ignored.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?
What is the base value for `tipoextremo`?
Why would you set `document.getElementById("tipoextremo").value = tipoextremo`?
Why are you setting `tipoextremo = tipoextremo`?
Why are you using `input[type=button]` instead of `button[type=button]`?
Why are you wrapping the button event handler in a function which is only called if that same button is clicked?
Please consider creating a fiddle where you can demonstrate where your error is happening

Comment: @choz ok i got it working by switching "input[type=button]" with "button[type=button]" and tipoextremo = tipoextremo was just a test because i wanted to see if the value was really being passed into that variables. Im drawing into a canvas, the last problem I have is that when I click in the radio buttons for my "round", "square" and "butt" type of corners it gets ignored and makes only get round corners and I get alert("Hi") messages in a increase by one everytime i click (I posted the changes in my code).